# SQL Dropping temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Which is a better practice for dropping table in a stored procedure ?

**Sample A**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tTable1') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #tTable1
CREATE TABLE #tTable1
```

or 
**Sample B**

```
CREATE TABLE #tTable1
select * from #tTable1
Drop TABLE #tTable1
```

Comment: What version of SQL? I assume some flavor of MS SQL?

Comment: Why not both? Check at the beginning and also drop at the end?

Comment: Sample A is better, to check existance of table is better

Answer (score 5):

You are dealing with *local* temporary tables.  You don't need to be so worried.

Stored procedures drop temporary tables automatically when they return, so you do not need to worry about temporary tables lingering.  It took me a while to get used to this behavior, but because this behavior is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms174979%28v%3Dsql.105%29), you can depend on it:

> - A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>     automatically when the stored procedure is finished.

This is how locally-declared temporary tables work in SQL Server.  That is simply their defined semantics.

Of course, you might be worried about a temporary table created *outside* the stored procedure.  But wantonly dropping such tables could be dangerous.

You do not have to worry about naming collisions either when multiple calls to a stored procedure:

> If a local temporary table is created in a stored procedure or
>   application that can be executed at the same time by several users,
>   the Database Engine must be able to distinguish the tables created by
>   the different users. The Database Engine does this by internally
>   appending a numeric suffix to each local temporary table name.

There are some nuances to all this.  Because temporary tables use a common name space for things like constraint names, you need to be careful if you add your own names.

There is nothing wrong with dropping a temporary table when it is no longer needed.  I am simply pointing that that this is not necessary.

As a matter of preference, I prefer table variables over temporary tables.  It is even more clear that their scope is within the stored procedure, the same way as other variables.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend both. I have coded both before in the same proc and no one has ever complained about redundant code or not following DRY. When the proc is done using the table, it is a good idea to drop it anyways so it is not using resources. Especially if the session is staying open for some reason, that table will persist until the session is closed or until you drop the table.

If you choose 1, go with the first option. If somehow bizarre data gets introduced in your table and you throw an exception from a function, the code may not make it to the drop section. Then if the same session runs the proc again, boom, object already exists. The exists check will drop the temp table no matter what when the proc is executed.